# Cytoscape.js Check for double-click on nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a possibility to bind a double-click Mouse Event to a node?
In the documentation, there is only 'click'.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14):

You can add a custom `doubleTap` event for Cytoscape like this:

```js
    var cy = $('#cy').cytoscape('get');
    var tappedBefore;
    var tappedTimeout;
    cy.on('tap', function(event) {
      var tappedNow = event.cyTarget;
      if (tappedTimeout && tappedBefore) {
        clearTimeout(tappedTimeout);
      }
      if(tappedBefore === tappedNow) {
        tappedNow.trigger('doubleTap');
        tappedBefore = null;
      } else {
        tappedTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ tappedBefore = null; }, 300);
        tappedBefore = tappedNow;
      }
    });
```

Then, you can subscribe for the new event. For example, if you need to detect double tab on nodes, do:

```js
    cy.on('doubleTap', 'node', function(event) { /* ... */ });
```

Nevertheless, I understant @maxkfranz point of view that this is not mobile-friendly solution.

Comment: this worked for me after I did changed tappedNow.trigger('doubleTap'); to this.trigger('doubleTap');

Comment: Yes, it's pretty easy to add your own custom events/gestures on top of the library.  I still think doubletap/doubleclick isn't very good UI in most cases, so I don't think it should be included in the library by default.  Maybe you would consider packing your code in an extension so it's reusable.  Extension scaffolding is automatic: http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/autoscaffolding

Comment: I find this solution not work well on IE11, and the solution @scebotari66 posted work well for me also on IE11.

Comment: I do not get a event.cyTarget . In my event I just get event.cy . is that the same as target?

Comment: ok I found out I have event.target, and it works, instead of event.cyTarget

Answer (score 3):

One of the core requirements of cy.js is that it should work equally well and as-consistently-as-possible across devices.  Double click is a carry over from PC days:  It often results in poor UI, and it is completely foreign to touch-based devices.  Therefore, we do not support it currently. -M

Comment: i think about 99% of people using cy would be using it on a PC anyway.

Comment: It depends on the app, and it depends on the use case.  Even on desktop computers, users rarely try to double click --- especially on the web.  There's nothing stopping you from using double clicks in your apps on top of built-in 'click' events.  The library, however, discourages you from doing so by not having a direct 'doubleclick' event.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a way to achieve this without `setTimeout`. The event has a `timeStamp` property with the values of UNIX time stamp when the event got triggered. So, here is the approach:

```
var doubleClickDelayMs = 350;
var previousTapStamp;

cy.on('tap', function(e) {
    var currentTapStamp = e.timeStamp;
    var msFromLastTap = currentTapStamp - previousTapStamp;

    if (msFromLastTap < doubleClickDelayMs) {
        e.target.trigger('doubleTap', e);
    }
    previousTapStamp = currentTapStamp;
});


cy.on('doubleTap', function(event, originalTapEvent) {
    ...
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scebotari66/84x7hxd0/4/

Answer (score 0):

thanks @fracz for the solution.
In my case I needed the tap position. If metadata from the original tap event are needed, don't forget passing and replacing the event, as the doubletap event doesn't contain all metadata.

```
var tappedBefore;
var tappedTimeout;

cy.on('tap', function(event) {
  var tappedNow = event.target;
  if (tappedTimeout && tappedBefore) {
    clearTimeout(tappedTimeout);
  }
  if(tappedBefore === tappedNow) {
    tappedNow.trigger('doubleTap', event);
    tappedBefore = null;
    originalTapEvent = null;
  } else {
    tappedTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ tappedBefore = null; }, 300);
    tappedBefore = tappedNow;
  }
});
```

and to use it:

```
cy.on('doubleTap', function (event, originalTapEvent) {
    event = originalTapEvent;
...
```

Besides, did someone do experiments with a combination of tapstart (index finger, use this event location) + tap(middle finger, location irrelevant only as selection confirmation) as an alternative? Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a strict double tap but works like it. It relies on [`node.selected()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#ele.selected)

When user taps/click once on a node it gets a state `selected`.
When user clicks again and the node is selected from before it works as a double click.

There is no need to track another state and use timeouts with this solution.

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  let node = evt.target;
  console.log('tapped ' + node.id());
  if (node.selected()) {
    console.log('selected ' + node.id());
  }
});
```

console log will then be

```
tapped <nodeId>
tapped <nodeId>
selected <nodeId>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [fixpoint/cytoscape-dblclick](https://github.com/fixpoint/cytoscape-dblclick) (MIT License) for a 3<sup>rd</sup>-party solution that is ready to use.